# Java: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: java, linux, undefined-symbol

I've been working on a Java project that uses a gui.jar file to import some classes. Everything was working fine until yesterday. Now, I can compile the .class files by the command

`javac -d ./bin -sourcepath ./src -classpath ./bin/gui.jar src/simulation/TestSimulateur.javac`

but when I try to execute the program with

`java -classpath bin:bin/gui.jar simulation.TestSimulateur`

I get the error

`java: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE make: *** [Makefile:47: carte1] Error 127`

I don't know much about how snap and the libraries work so I'm not sure about the root of the problem. It's strange that the problem only appears when I run it on VSCode, while it works fine if I run it on the normal Linux terminal.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find how to solve the problem. As I've said, I'm newbie on Linux system. Between my attempts, I tried to reinstall VSCode, updating the system and updating snap packages, but none of those worked.

Answer (score 21):

Though I have already answered it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462295/ubuntu-22-04-both-eye-of-gnome-and-gimp-failing-with-undefined-symbol-error/1462494#1462494)

The issue with how the VSCode Snap package libraries are configured to be used.
They are setting the following environment variable `GTK_PATH`, which gets inherited by the VSCode Terminal.

Unsetting the environment variable in the VSCode terminal does seem to work for me.

```bash
unset GTK_PATH
```

As a slightly more permanent workaround, you can also unset `GTK_PATH` in your VS Code user settings, run "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)" and add this to your `settings.json`:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "GTK_PATH": ""
    }
```

**Update 2: 2024-03-09**

It seems the VSCode Snap package(version **1.87.1**) has introduced even more environment variables for GTK Toolkit.

I have to additionally unset the following environment variables for additional GTK Built Applications:

```bash
unset GIO_MODULE_DIR
```

For people looking at solving this issue with the VSCode Snap Package installation can use the following in their `settings.json`:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "GTK_PATH": null,
    "GIO_MODULE_DIR": null,
},
```

Comment: unsetting from vscode terminal didn't work for me. but when i added it in launch.json (as mentioned in the other answer) it worked!

Comment: Are you launching a debug/task from VSCode UI?

Comment: yes for debugging and breakpoints. so basically I'm using F5 (or run > start debugging)

Comment: @Reyno, you could try setting the environment variable to be empty in the `setting.json`. That should also help in resolving it for now.

Comment: Thanks @AmeyaVS, that worked as simple as it is. It still gives me a lot of warnings but at least it compiles. Would you mind clearing more or less where the bug comes from and how this solve the problem?

Comment: @LeonardoMonteiro, this bug is a manifestation of the VSCode Snap Package specifying the `GTK_PATH` environment variable within the script in VSCode which is inherited in the Terminal Process in VSCode. You can find relevant discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179274).

Answer (score 6):

I've also encountered this bug after a recent ubuntu update. I think this is related to the snap and vscode.

One simple solution is to uninstall vscode in snap with

```bash
sudo snap remove code
```

Then, install vscode with apt shown in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

```bash
sudo apt install ./<file>.deb
```